# What may I infer from knowing that some data set's covariance matrix is singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics

I know what a matrix being singular means. I know what a covariance matrix is. What I'd like to know, though, is what I can *infer* about a data set if I know that its covariance matrix is singular.

The driving reason for this question is that I've implemented LDA and have found myself hitting my head against singular covariance matrices (and the subsequent failure of the naive LDA algorithm). I've since moved to support vector machines (because I refuse to implement the conditioning for other LDA algorithms), but I still feel like there's some grain of education left to be had from the experience.

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241997/about-linear-dependence-in-covariance-matrix-and-implications-on-the-variables

Comment: I would suggest looking into whether or not certain random variables are independent. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $\text{cov}(X,Y)=0$.